# Static and dynamic types

Tags: java, inheritance

I am preparing for an exam in java. Please have a look at the following two exercises .(I have solutions, but the solutions are without explanations) so If anybody could check my explanations, that would be greatly appreciated.

1)

```
public interface Sale{}
public abstract class Clothing{}
public class Jacket extends Clothing implements Sale{}
public class LeatherJacket extends Jacket{}
```

Which of the following are possible:

```
Sale var1 = new LeatherJacket();
```

is possible, since LeatherJacket is a subclass of Jacket and Jacket implements sale? (I'm just guessing here).

```
Sale var2 = new Sale();
```

impossible. You cannot create an object of an interface type.

```
Clothing var3 = new Clothing();
```

impossible. You cannot create an object of an abstract class.

```
Clothing var4 = new LeatherJacket();
```

possible, but why?

```
Jacket var5 = new LeatherJacket();
```

possible, but why exactly?

```
LeatherJacket var6  = new Object();
```

not possible, but why not?

Answer (score 0):

```
Clothing var4 = new LeatherJacket();
```

LeatherJacket extends Jacket that extend Clothing.

```
Jacket var5 = new LeatherJacket();
```

LeatherJacket extends Jacket

```
LeatherJacket var6  = new Object();
```

Object is the superClass of all. You can't do it but viceversa yes  Object o= new LeatherJacket();

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Clothing var4 = new LeatherJacket();
> ```
>
> possible, but why?

This is allowed because `LeatherJacket` is a derived class of `Clothing`. It is **not** instantiating through the abstract class `Clothing`. It wrote `new LeatherJacket()` and not `new Clothing()`.

---

> ```
> Jacket var5 = new LeatherJacket();
> ```
>
> possible, but why exactly?

This is allowed because all leather jackets are Jacket. But the reverse is untrue. It is like all Lions are animals, then you can write it as:

```
Animal lion = new Lion();  //where Lion extends Animal
```

But you can't write it as:

```
Lion lion = new Animal();  //not all animals are lions
```

---

> ```
> LeatherJacket var6  = new Object();
> ```
>
> not possible, but why not?

The reason is same as the previous explanation. `Object` is at the highest hierarchy in Java, every class is a subclass of class `Object`. Hence being at the top of the hierarchy, this will not be allowed. However, this will be allowed:

```
Object var6 = new LeatherJacket();  //allowed (all leather jackets are objects)
LeatherJacket var 6 = new Object(); //not allowed (not all objects are leather jackets)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detialed answer. So in the first one var1 is a variable of type Sale and it stores an object of LeatherJacket, right? Then the following must also be true: Sale var7 = new Jacket();?

Comment: @DerDieDasEhochWas Yes you are right on both of your assumptions. If it helps you may accept **one** solution from here which helped you most by clicking the hollow looking tick beside the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a hierarchy like this, you can perceived it via a venn diagram:

[image]

The following should give you a very good clue what is allowed and not allowed:

```
Object o = new Clothing();        //not allowed (Clothing is abstract!)
Object o = new Jacket();          //allowed (jacket is a subset of object)
OBject o = new LaatherJacket();   //allowed (leather jacket is a subset of object)

Clothing c = new Object();        //not allowed (Object is not a subset of clothing, cannot assume object is definitely a Clothing)
Clothing c = new Jacket();        //allowed (jacket is a subset of Clothing)
Clothing c = new LaatherJacket(); //allowed (leather jacket is a subset of Clothing)

Jacket j = new Object();          //not allowed (Object is not a subset of jacket, cannot assume object is definitely a jacket)
Jacket j = new Clothing();        //not allowed (Clothing is abstract!)
Jacket j = new LeatherJacket();   //allowed (leather jacket is a subset of jacket)

LeatherJacket j = new Object;     //not allowed (Object is not a subset of jacket, cannot assume object is definitely a leather jacket)
LeatherJacket j = new Clothing(); //not allowed (Clothing is abstract!)
LeatherJacket j = new Jacket();   //not allowed (Jacket is not a subset of jacket, cannot assume jacket is definitely a leatherjacket)
```